# How to SUMIFS horizontally with a criteria and offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]I'm having trouble with an excel formula where i'm trying to get the sum of all numbers in the row which are at 1 column offset with the criteria.
Eg. A1 = Price | B1 = $1000| C1 = Price| D1 = $1500 and so on....
Answer should be 1000+1500= $2500

I tried `=SUMIF(1:1,"Price",OFFSET(1:1,0,1))` but gives me error!

Comment: Where is the error? Where do you place the formula?

Comment: The placement of the formula shouldn't be impacting on the result.

Comment: I suspect that when you try to shift an entire row to the right or left, that the right or left column is now sitting outside of the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUMIF(A20:ZZ20, "Price", OFFSET(20:20, 0, 1, 1, COLUMN() - 2))

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have the cell with your formula in the same row, so it is a cyclic reference that gives you the error.

You can cut `1:1` before the cell with the `SUMIF`:

```
=SUMIF(OFFSET(1:1, 0, 0, 1, COLUMN() - 2), "Price", OFFSET(1:1, 0, 1, 1, COLUMN() - 2))
```

Comment: This will sum all numbers. I think OP wants only sum offset cells of word `Price`.

Comment: Hi @Kishkin thanks for the answer, however the formula must use offset as there are various other numbers and text in the row.

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the excel for better understanding of the excel row

Comment: @Yusuf Thought you used Google Sheets. This should work in Excel.

Comment: This worked=SUMIF(A20:ZZ20, "Price", OFFSET(20:20, 0, 1, 1, COLUMN() - 2))

Comment: @Yusuf where did you place it? Which cell?

Answer (score 0):

a possible solution is to offset your reference ranges.  This means you will not be able to do an entire row reference.  In your limited example your formula would wind up looking like this:

```
=SUMIF(A1:Q1,"price",B1:R1)
```

so you sum range will be limited to one less column than what is available to the sheet to allow for the second range (equal in size range) to be shifted one column to the right.

[image: poc]

#### SIDE NOTE

Idealy you would want to arrange your data in a table. I understand this may not always be possible when dealing with 3rd party data dumps, limited VBA knowledge, and large amounts of data.

[image]